# Congruence Inconsistency

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, congruences

I have a question about congruency...

I understand that: 
$$
12 \equiv 7 \bmod  5
$$
$$
\text {is equivalent to:}
$$
$$
5|12-7
$$
but this doesn't seem to hold for:
$$
2 \equiv 8 \bmod 6
$$
$$
\text {the conclusion i come to is:}
$$
$$
6|-6
$$
are these equivalent??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $6\mid-6$. That simply means that there is some integer $k$ such that $-6=6k$, and there is: take $k=-1$. There is no requirement that the integer be positive.

Comment: Ahh ok I think I misunderstood the definition of the | Thanks!

Comment: @NightMarcher: You’re welcome! Just to be sure: $a\mid b$ means simply that there is some integer $k$ such that $b=ak$.

Comment: does it also hold for the reverse? so does a|b mean there is some integer k such that a = bk?

Comment: @NightMarcher: No. For instance, $3\mid 12$, since $12=3\cdot 4$ and $4$ is an integer, but there is no integer $k$ such that $3=12k$. The only time you have both $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$ is when $a=b$ or $a=-b$.

Comment: I'm glad I asked...thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @NightMarcher: My pleasure!